# Loop through the end of a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to loop through a Django queryset, starting at the last record and going back 1,000 records at a time. I'm able to get the last 1,000 records with the following query:

```
employees = Employee.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1000]
```

Say my queryset is 10,0000 results. How can I go from 8,000 to 9,000? Do I have to use .count() to get the total record count? My full queryset is 12 million records so I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly where your problem is? Do you want to be able to retrieve all records 1000 at a time starting from the last, without having to call count()?

Comment: Are you looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/ ?

Comment: @TGO I'm trying to keep an elasticsearch index up to date. The package I'm using Elasticsearch-DSL-Django, starts at the first record and goes all the way to the end in order to populate recent records. So I'm trying to simply start from the end and go back until no new records are found.

Comment: You can use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.reverse) for getting the latest records and [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) method to know the number of recors, also `count` is probably the best method to know the number of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up. I could not do it without using count(). But I did switch to raw SQL for that, which is supposed to be faster.

```
from django.db import connection
from employee.models import Employee

# count records using raw SQL (best for larger datasets)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_employee;')
(count,) = cursor.fetchone()

records_to_index = 100000
batch_size = 3000

# loop through batch starting at end of queryset going backwards
# continue until records_to_index is met
for end in range(count, count - records_to_index, -batch_size):
    # add 1 to ensure records do not overlap
    start = end - batch_size + 1

    employees = Employee.objects.all().order_by('id')[start:end]

    for employee in employees:
        # work with object
```